# How to know if there is damp or mold behind wall?

Tags: water, walls

I previously had housing use a product to seal over a damp wall.  How do I know the wall is ok on the inside?

It may also be the case that the damp has dried on the inside so in this case, again, how can I test of the inside of the wall is ok?

Thanks.

Comment: So you used some unnamed product on some unspecified wall type that had some sort of dampness somewhere.  Now you want to know if all of that dried and if there is anyway to test the inside.  Hmmm....

Comment: @jwh20 they(the landlord) used a named product(which to me is unknown) on a specific wall(with damp on it).  I want to know if they have done a surface job only or if the inside of the wall may have damp or mould.  A damp meter wouldnt work if the water has dried.

Answer (score 1):

The only 'test' the inside of the wall is to actual visually inspect it and to acquire access to do that would require 'damaging' the wall. The wall can be repaired but I'm assuming that you don't want to do that due to your lease and the cost.

There is a way that might be allowed under your lease and is relatively inexpensive and easy to repair. This is the use of an [inspection camera](https://www.homedepot.com/b/Tools-Power-Tools-Inspection-Cameras/N-5yc1vZc2gm) which is a device that uses a skinny tube with a camera on the end, much like the doctor uses to look down a patients throat or for a colonoscopy. They can be rented for the day. To use, a small hole is drilled through the wall covering, and that hole might be smaller than the maximum allowed by your lease for general use like hanging pictures and shelves. Even if not, it is small enough that it could be repaired fairly easy though due to the many different types of wall coverings I consider that a different question and answer